# “We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the Setup log files”

Tags: partitioning, windows-8.1, setup

I am trying to install Windows 8.1 on an existing partition. I can’t format it because i have like dozens of GBs of data there. I receive this message when i select the partition. I am installing the system from DVD in EFI mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occured because the disk did not have an EFI system partition. I moved all data off the disk and let Setup create the needed partition layout.

Comment: Another scenario in which that message kept popping up for me was when I had several hard drives in my tower.  I unplugged all but one, and then it would finally get past that error message.